# Marking IMAP email as read not working

Tags: php, imap

ok so my question is clearly within the title.
What am i doing wrong with this code?

Input:

```
function mark_email_as_read() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['talent_user_id']) and $_SESSION['talent_user_id'] > 0) {

    $peek = $this->peek();  
    $uid = $this->common_model->search_get($this->url, 'uid');
    $msgno = imap_msgno($this->imap, $uid);
    $user_id = $_SESSION[$this->session_prefix.'_user_id'];
    $acc = $this->common_model->search_get($this->url,'acc');
    $folder = $this->common_model->search_get($this->url,'accfolder');

    $ssl = false;

    $ssl=($ssl==false)?"/novalidate-cert":"";

    $host = $this->email_accounts[$this->the_helpdesk_view][$this->the_helpdesk_company]['server'];
    $port = $this->email_accounts[$this->the_helpdesk_view][$this->the_helpdesk_company]['port'];
    $folder = $this->email_accounts[$this->the_helpdesk_view][$this->the_helpdesk_company]['folder'];
    $user = $this->email_accounts[$this->the_helpdesk_view][$this->the_helpdesk_company]['user'];
    $pass = $this->email_accounts[$this->the_helpdesk_view][$this->the_helpdesk_company]['pass'];

        $this->imap = imap_open("{"."$host:$port/imap$ssl"."}$folder", $user, $pass) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

        $imap = $this->imap;

        $msgnum = imap_msgno($imap, $msgno);

        if ($peek==true) {
            imap_clearflag_full($imap, $msgnum, '\flagged');
            echo"oh dear";
        } else {
            imap_setflag_full($imap, $msgnum, '\seen');
            echo"set";
        }
        echo "its working i think";
        imap_headers($this->imap);
        echo"well its got here";
    }
}
```

Output:

Well it doesnt show anything but, it will not mark as Seen. could you help?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Yes i do have error reporting on

Comment: Nope, i recieve an output of "Set, its working i think and well its got here."

Comment: Can you show us peek()?